ESP32-WROOM-32DA IO pin 25 Always HIGH
I have esp32-wroom-32DA and i was connected one switch into IO pin 25 to take a digital reading. i already pull down that pin. the problem is digital read of this pin is always HIGH. i was check the connection between the switch and the pin even switch is off digital read of the IO pin 25 shows as HIGH. can anyone please help me with this mater.



I check the conectivity between the IO pin and Switch, Its seems fine.
I check the voltage By switching the Switch On and Off, when switch is On there is 3.3V and 0V when switch is off. also check the puldown resistor.
Using the arduino IDE i set the IO pin as low and read the Digital state that time the IO pin is shows LOW . but when i try to read the IO pin as Input it is show HIGH.


The footprint doesn't looks like you have an ESP32-WROOM-32DA as the module supposed to have a dual antenna, and in fact for that pin position, it is an NC. So what exactly is your module? P.S. on the PCD design, the antenna area should not have copper fill.
